# I have multiple dataframes in a list. How to print their names?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in multiple files and adding them to a list:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import ntpath


path = r'C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder3' 

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.dat") #.dat files only

mylist = []

for filename in all_files:
    name = ntpath.basename(filename) # for renaming the DF
    name = name.replace('.dat','') # remove extension
    try:
        name = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', engine='python')
        mylist.append(name) 
    except:
        print(f'File not read:{filename}')
```

Now I want to just display the DFs in this list.

This is what I've tried:

```
for thing in mylist:
    print(thing.name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

And

```
for item in mylist:
    print(item)
```

But that just prints the whole DF content.

Comment: You add the df to the list. It doesn’t have its variable name anymore. If you want that, it’s better to add them to a dictionary and use the name as the key and the df as the corresponding value.

Comment: its an object, do this `mydict = {}; for filename in path:mydict[filename] = pd.read_csv(filename)`

Comment: `mylist.append((name,filename));`

Comment: The dictionary method worked. Now I need to figure out how to get them out of the dictionary. :)

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for that.

Writing to dict:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import ntpath


path = r'C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder3' 

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.dat") #.dat files only

mydict = {}

for filename in all_files:
    name = ntpath.basename(filename) # for renaming the DF
    name = name.replace('.dat','') # remove extension
    try:
       mydict[name] = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', engine='python')
    except:
        print(f'File not read:{filename}')
```

To read a df (say `filename1`) again:

```
df = mydict['filename1']
```

or to iterate over all df's in `mydict`:

```
for df in mydict.values():
    # use df...
```

or:

```
for key in mydict:
    print(key)
    df = mydict[key]
    # use df...
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     name = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', engine='python')
>     mylist.append(name)
> ```

Here, `name` is a dataframe, not the name of your dataframe.

To add name to your dataframe, use

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', engine='python')
df_name="Sample name"
mylist.append({'data':df, 'name':df_name})
```

```
>>> print(thing['name'])
Sample name
```

Comment: Don't think that works: `C:\Users\seanc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:9: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: My bad! `df.name ` tried to access a column of the dataframe. The above method creates a dict with keys as `data` and `name`